Distribution of sample covariance times inverse covariance times sample covariance
I want to understand the distribution of the random variable:
$$S_n = \frac{1}{n^2} 1'\hat \Sigma \Sigma ^{-1} \hat \Sigma 1$$.
1 is a vector of ones of size n, and the variance is of size nxn. $\hat \Sigma$ is an estimate, possibly regularized.
We can assume normality if necessary.
$S_n$ shows up as the maximum equilibrium Sharpe ratio under some conditions.
In particular, I want to understand how $S_n$ changes when either n grows or when $\hat \Sigma$ is a worse approximation of the covariance matrix.
My intuition is that n should grow in both cases, and I checked with simulations but would like theoretical results.

Hi: that sounds like a complicated question. you'd probably have to get your hands on this ( I couldn't find a free copy ) and then do the wild ride through the reference jungle and hope that there is something relevant to your question. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037722171730749X

This looks more relevant but still not free. science direct is known to make it pretty difficult to find free copies.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407616300598

Thanks for the references! I'll try to access through my university. Worse case I'll email the authors :)

yes. sometimes I'll email the author and get a hit and sometimes not.
